# C# Specify generic type parameter once and use it throughout class

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have a class `ClassWhichDoesThings` which makes various calls to methods such as

```
DoSomething<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
DoAnotherThing<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
AndAnother<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
```

throughout the class.

Is it possible to specify the generic type in one place (like a variable but not determined at runtime) without anything outside of the class having to also pass a generic type (avoiding `ClassWhichDoesThings<T>`) such that the method calls become something like:

```
Type WriteTypeOnce = typeof(TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce);

DoSomething<WriteTypeOnce>();
DoAnotherThing<WriteTypeOnce>();
AndAnother<WriteTypeOnce>();
```

The objective here being that if I want to change the Type, I don't have to do a find and replace on 20 different method calls for example.

Essentially I want a generic class which specifies its own generic type privately.

Edit: In other words, I'm trying to better organise code which is completely private to a class but focuses on dealing with a single Type. For example, let's say I wanted to add the method:

```
public TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce CreateAThing(string input){ ... }
```

I want it to be very clear that this class focuses on `TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce` or `T` so that it's easy to write another method with `T` but without `T` being specified when creating the class...

Comment: This is a really peculiar request. Why not just make the class generic, is it such a problem to refer to `MyClass<T>`? Secondly, are those methods you list public? What are those methods doing?

Comment: @DavidG It is definitely a bit strange (which might mean I'm not thinking the right way). Essentially what I have is boilerplate code which I copy and paste as various different implementations (classes) whilst also changing the type of various methods and return types etc (repeated throughout the class). It would be convenient to be able to speed up this process and avoid errors where a Type gets forgotten to be updated. (Generic base class or shared implementation not desired here).

One solution that just came to me is using an internal generic class. I don't want the generic type public.

Comment: I'm not sure if how `List<T>` has `Add(T)`, `Exists(Predicate<T>)`, `ForEach(Action<T>)`, etc. is something you want to avoid.  You said _avoiding `ClassWhichDoesThings<T>`_ But this lets you just write `T`, so if you change the type, you don't have to change code with search and replace because it's just literally `T` in the code.  I mean, so far, it sounds like you're just describing generic classes.

Comment: @Wyck I think the key difference I'm looking for is that the generic type parameter not be public to any calling code. The generic type here is irrelevant to the caller. I'm thinking using a nested generic class might make sense here.

Comment: Are you looking for [Type.MakeGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=net-6.0) whereby you can create a generic instance from a runtime type?  And I'm concerned about how you said that shared implementation is *not* desired.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish if there will be no shared implementation.  I think your example code needs to be fleshed out a bit more.

Comment: @Wyck Regarding Type.MakeGenericType not really - quite simply I'm looking for convenience and avoidance of errors when dealing with reuse of boilerplate code. That is, classes which have a common starting point/structure but could end up with completely different implementations. The commonality is that each of these classes tends to operate on one particular Type which means I have to go through and update the Type multiple times when creating a new class (sometimes forgetting to update one).

Comment: The [_global using directive_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/globalusingdirective) in C# 10 may solve this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink why you have all that boiler plate in the first place

Comment: Are you looking for [Create a code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depended on the case you can create internal generic method or class and use it, making the class itself basically a wrapper:

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly int Data = 1; 
    private Generic<ActualType> Instance;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        Instance = new(this);
    }

    public int SomeMethod => Instance.SomeMethodImpl();
    public int SomeMethod1 => Instance.SomeMethodImpl2();

    private class Generic<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>
    {
        private readonly SomeClass _instance;

        // if needed - pass the parent class instance to reference it's internal data
        // if not - remove both ctors and 
        // just init with Generic<ActualType> Instance = new();
        public Generic(SomeClass instance) 
        {
            _instance = instance;
        }
        public int SomeMethodImpl() => DoSomething<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();

        public int SomeMethodImpl2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_instance.Data); // use parent internal data if needed
            DoAnotherThing<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
            return AndAnother<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach can be [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive):

```cs
using TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce = System.Int32;
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeMethod => DoSomething<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
    public int SomeMethod1() 
    {
        DoAnotherThing<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
        return AndAnother<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to do what I've asked. I'm not sure if I might be approaching the problem in the wrong way as this method would probably add some bloat to the classes but it definitely allows for a generic type to be used and kept private. Ideally there would be some Private generic type variable that could be used but again maybe that's a strange request.

Comment: @Tito please see the update.

Comment: Wow interesting, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a method with a type parameter

```cs
static void DoAllThings<T>()
{
    DoSomething<T>();
    DoAnotherThing<T>();
    AndAnother<T>();   
}
```

and call it with

```cs
DoAllThings<TheTypeIWantToSpecifyOnce>();
```

Note also that `T` is specified on the method, not on the class and is known only inside the class.

This can also be a local function, i.e., a function inside a method.

But to be clear: Generics are not dynamic, i.e., you cannot use a runtime type (given as a variable or parameter of type `System.Type`) as an argument for a generic type parameter.